# SVN Export Change log to a specific folder

Tags: svn, export

I'm using the below command to get the change log from SVN.

```
C:\Sync\BatchFiles>svn log http://10.32.10.56/svn/Repository/trunk -v -r {2011
    -03-25}:{2011-03-29} --xml  file://C:/Sync/XMLFiles/SVN_Export.xml
```

I need to copy the log file to a specific folder on my local system.But I get the below error when I run the command.

```
svn: Only relative paths can be specified after a URL
```

Can someone please let me know if it is possible to specify the output location of the log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--xml` only says the output should be in xml, it does not take in a file to write to. It just outputs to console. You can do redirect it to a file:

```
svn log http://10.32.10.56/svn/Repository/trunk -v -r {2011-03-25}:{2011-03-29} --xml 
    > C:/Sync/XMLFiles/SVN_Export.xml
```